# (True or false) If $A\subset\mathbb{R}$ is the union of an open and a closed set then $A^c$ is also of this form.

Tags: general-topology, real-numbers

(Prove or disprove) If $A\subset\mathbb{R}$ and $A=V\cup K$ where V is an open set and K is a closed set, then $A^c$ can also be seen as the union of an open and a closed set.

Comment: Well, by de Morgan's Law $A^c=V^c\cap K^c$. And we know $V^c$ is closed and $K^c$ is open.

Comment: Also, $V^c\cap K^c = (\bar{V} \cup K)^c \cup (Fr(V)-K)$. And $(\bar{V} \cup K)^c$ is open.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HINT:

The key to this question is to try looking at sets which are NOT of the desired form. That is, look for a set $B\subset\mathbb{R}$ which cannot be written as the union of an open and a closed set. If we can then also show that the complement $B^{c}$ can be written as the union of an open and a closed set, then $B^{c}$ is a counterexample to the claim and we are done.

First note that, by definition, if $U\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ is a non-empty open set, then we can find an interval $(a,b)$ with $a<b$ so that $(a,b)\subseteq U$. Thus, if a set $A$ is the union of an open and a closed set, then either $A$ contains such a non-empty interval, or $A$ is closed (that is, the 'open part' is empty).

Next note that it is very easy to construct a set which is not closed, just remove a limit point. With this in mind, we can now construct a set $B$ which is not the union of an open and a closed set.

ANSWER:

Define $B\subset\mathbb{R}$ by $$B=\{1/n:n\in\mathbb{N} \}=\{1,1/2,1/3,...\}.$$ 
Suppose we could find an open set $V$ and a closed set $K$ such that $B=K\cup V$. Notice that $B$ does not contain any non-empty intervals (each point of $B$ is isolated). Therefore, $V$ must be empty, and so $B=K$ is closed. However, $0\notin B$ is a limit point of $B$, so $B$ is not closed. This contradiction shows that $B$ cannot be the union of an open and a closed set.

It only remains to show that the complement $B^{c}$ is the union of an open and a closed set. Let $K=(-\infty,0]$, so $K$ is a closed set. Let $V$ be defined by $$V=(1,\infty)\cup \bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\left(\frac{1}{n+1},\frac{1}{n} \right).$$ Since $V$ is a union of open intervals, $V$ is an open set. Finally, note that $B^{c}=K\cup V$ is of the desired form. Therefore, the claim is false as $B^{c}$ is a counterexample (you may like trying to find your own counterexample using similar reasoning).